$\langle v'',v\times v'\rangle $ is constant. Can you prove $v$ lies on a plane?
I tried to make the title short but of course there are additional hypothesis.

Let $v:I\to \mathbb{S}^2$ be a regular curve parametrized by arc-length. This is to say that the tangent $v'$ is also a curve $v':I\to \mathbb{S}^2$ into the unitary sphere. Then suppose $v$ satisfies
$$\langle v'', v\times v'\rangle = c,$$
for some constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$. I would like to prove that $v$ lies on a plane (and therefore describes a circle).

What I've tried: first, we have some coordinate-free conclusions. For example, $\{v,v',v\times v'\}$ yields a $\mathbb{R}^3$-orthonormal basis for every $s\in I$. Using that $v$ and $v'$ are unitary, one can find that
$$v''=-v+c(v\times v').$$
I couldn't see much more in that direction.
Also tried to use spherical coordinates for $v$, i.e. writing $v$ as
$$v=(\cos \theta \cos \varphi, \cos \theta \sin \varphi, \sin \theta),$$
for certain functions $\theta,\varphi:I\to \mathbb{R}$. Then both $\langle v'', v\times v'\rangle = c$ and $v''=-v+c(v\times v')$ yield some equations, but also I wasn't able to get anywhere with them.
Solving this problem is related to showing that non-developable ruled Weingarten surfaces are given by screw motion surfaces (kind of ruled helicoids).

A curve lies on a plane iff its torsion is $0$.
Let us derive your equation
$\langle v'', v\wedge v'\rangle=c$
we get $\langle v''',v\wedge v'\rangle+\langle v'', v'\wedge v'\rangle+ \langle v'', v\wedge v''\rangle =0$
The second term is 0 ($v'\wedge v'=0$) as well as the third ($v\wedge v''$ is orthogonal to $v''$).
Therefore  $v'''$ is orthogonal to $v'$  and the torsion is $0$.

Indeed very simple. Thanks!

But wait, your answer shows that $v'''$ is orthogonal to $v\times v'$, right? Also, the torsion formula is $\tau = \frac{\langle v''',v''\times v'\rangle}{|v'\times v''|^2}$. How would $v'''$ orthogonal to $v'$ prove that the torsion is zero?

Your idea is right. I just needed to play a bit more with the expressions to show that $\tau \equiv 0$. Thank you again
